# End-of-file error reading text file

Tags: matrix, input, fortran, readfile

I have got a problem in running the blew program for reading a text file as input file. This input file is like a matrix with 3 columns -- 3 numbers with format of (3(F3.6,1x)) -- and 4368 rows.

The input file is:

```
602340.440000 129706.190000 28.892939
602340.880000 129706.390000 28.955128
602884.500000 128780.700000 29.876873
602884.380000 128781.190000 29.875114
602884.250000 128781.660000 29.885448
602884.130000 128782.150000 29.895996
602883.940000 128782.630000 29.899380
602883.810000 128783.120000 29.903221
602883.690000 128783.590000 29.907070
```

PROGRAM is:

```
  USE BIEF
  USE DECLARATIONS_TELEMAC2D
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER LNG,LU, ITRAC,I, NSOM,J, K, NDOWN
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: NLINE =4368
  DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: BATHY_RADIER_up= 29.84D0
  DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: DEPTH_up = 2.15D0
  REAL :: A(5000),B(5000),C(5000)
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: XPOLYD(14), YPOLYD(14), INPOLYD(14)
  COMMON/INFO/LNG,LU

  DOUBLE PRECISION XPOLY(6), YPOLY(6),COTE_RADIER_up


   NSOM = 6
   XPOLY(1) = 602883.13
   XPOLY(2) = 602886.15
   XPOLY(3) = 602887.15
   XPOLY(4) = 602905.46
   XPOLY(5) = 602902.52
   XPOLY(6) = 602884.13


   YPOLY(1) = 128779.99
   YPOLY(2) = 128780.80
   YPOLY(3) = 128777.12
   YPOLY(4) = 128741.21
   YPOLY(5) = 128739.75
   YPOLY(6) = 128775.96



  AT = 0.D0


  CALL OS( 'X=0     ' , X=U )
  CALL OS( 'X=0     ' , X=V )


  IF(CDTINI(1:10).EQ.'COTE NULLE'.OR.
 *   CDTINI(1:14).EQ.'ZERO ELEVATION') THEN
    CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , H , H  , H , 0.D0 )
    CALL OS( 'X=X-Y   ' , H , ZF , H , 0.D0 )
  ELSEIF(CDTINI(1:14).EQ.'COTE CONSTANTE'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:18).EQ.'CONSTANT ELEVATION') THEN
    CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , H , H  , H , COTINI )
    CALL OS( 'X=X-Y   ' , H , ZF , H , 0.D0   )
  ELSEIF(CDTINI(1:13).EQ.'HAUTEUR NULLE'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:10).EQ.'ZERO DEPTH') THEN
    CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , H , H  , H , 0.D0  )
  ELSEIF(CDTINI(1:17).EQ.'HAUTEUR CONSTANTE'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:14).EQ.'CONSTANT DEPTH') THEN
    CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , H , H  , H , HAUTIN )
  ELSEIF(CDTINI(1:13).EQ.'PARTICULIERES'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:10).EQ.'PARTICULAR'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:07).EQ.'SPECIAL') THEN


    NDOWN = 14

  XPOLYD(1) = 602883.13
  XPOLYD(2) = 602886.15
  XPOLYD(3) = 602864.47
  XPOLYD(4) = 602837.90
  XPOLYD(5) = 602821.91
  XPOLYD(6) = 602649.77
  XPOLYD(7) = 602634.35
  XPOLYD(8) = 602345.08
  XPOLYD(9) = 602326.07
  XPOLYD(10) = 602619.31
  XPOLYD(11) = 602638.33
  XPOLYD(12) = 602811.64
  XPOLYD(13) = 602831.52
  XPOLYD(14) = 602857.16


  YPOLYD(1) = 128779.99
  YPOLYD(2) = 128780.80
  YPOLYD(3) = 128867.74
  YPOLYD(4) = 128936.74
  YPOLYD(5) = 128953.95
  YPOLYD(6) = 129105.43  
  YPOLYD(7) = 129143.43
  YPOLYD(8) = 129713.38
  YPOLYD(9) = 129708.26
  YPOLYD(10) = 129136.41
  YPOLYD(11) = 129094.72 
  YPOLYD(12) = 128941.16      
  YPOLYD(13) = 128931.09
  YPOLYD(14) = 128865.81

  PRINT *, 'opening file'
  DO 10 J=1,NPOIN 
   IF(INPOLY(X(J),Y(J),XPOLY,YPOLY,NSOM)) THEN
   PRINT *, 'upstream area'
      H%R(J)=MAX(0.D0,COTE_RADIER_up-ZF%R(J))
      U%R(J)=0.0D0
      PRINT *, 'upstream area'
      write(lu,*) 'upstream ....',J,H%r(J)

   ELSE
    IF(INPOLY(X(J),Y(J),XPOLYD,YPOLYD,NDOWN)) THEN
     OPEN(unit =90, FILE = 'cunnette_xyz.txt', FORM='FORMATTED')
     PRINT *, 'downstream area'
     READ(90,*) A(K),B(K),C(K)
     PRINT *, 'already read'
      DO K=1,NLINE
     PRINT *, "number of lines read:", NLINE
        IF(A(K).EQ.X(J).AND.B(K).EQ.Y(J)) then
          PRINT *, 'Nodes are inside'
          H%R(K)=0.45D0
          U%R(K)=0.D0
        ELSE
          H%R(K)=0.0D0
          U%R(K)=0.0D0
        ENDIF
      ENDDO
     CLOSE(90)
     ENDIF
   ENDIF

10    CONTINUE

  ELSE
    IF(LNG.EQ.1) THEN
    WRITE(LU,*) 'CONDIN : CONDITION INITIALE NON PREVUE : ',CDTINI
    ENDIF
    IF(LNG.EQ.2) THEN
    WRITE(LU,*) 'CONDIN: INITIAL CONDITION UNKNOWN: ',CDTINI
    ENDIF
    STOP
  ENDIF

  IF(NTRAC.GT.0) THEN
    DO ITRAC=1,NTRAC
      CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , X=T%ADR(ITRAC)%P , C=TRAC0(ITRAC) )
    ENDDO
  ENDIF

  CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , VISC , VISC , VISC , PROPNU )

  RETURN
  END
```

The error message when running is:

> at line read file: Fortran runtime error: End of file.

My last output is 'downstream area' aftre open Command. Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Please provide the first few lines of your input file.

Comment: This isn't the complete example (there's no `end`), so in the full program do you set the value of `k` at any point?  As with the comment above, please indicate the structure of the file.  It may also be better if you could provide a completely contained example, such as in [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting fortran runtime error: end of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584283/getting-fortran-runtime-error-end-of-file)

Comment: Without the full program and the data file ... who knows? Do you even open the right file (you should be using `STATUS='OLD'`)? Notice there is no `read` statement in your do loop. How does the **full output** of your program look like? Is `'downstream area'` printed? Is `'already read'` printed?

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. I am more betting he is not opening the right file at all.

Comment: In your other question you use a filename `'cunnette_xyz.txt'` rather than `'cunnette_xyz'` as here.  As with Vladimir F's comment, are you sure the file is correctly referenced?

Comment: @francescalus, thanks, I modified the post putting the whole program.

Comment: @VladimirF, thanks, I added STATUS='OLD' but the same problem :( yes both 'downstream area' and 'already read' are printed

Comment: @VladimirF, the cause of not opening the right file is also mentioned in the referenced question: *A common reason for the error you report is that the program doesn't find the file it is trying to open.* This is a duplicate.

Comment: @francescalus, As the text file is in the same folder, there is no need to put the format. Am I right?

Comment: @trincot, the inputfile is added in the post

Comment: You still did not correct the file name! If there is a file named just *cunnette_xyz*, delete it!

Comment: @VladimirF, but after OPEN command, it prints the 'downstream area'.

Comment: Well, that is info you should *certainly* put in your question. It seems quite important to know what the last output is you got.

Comment: @trincot, I just put the last output in question. Could you please tel me if READ(90,*) A(K),B(K),C(K) is correct?

Comment: @trincot, K is defined at first as interger. could you help me please?

Comment: See also [another question about the `open` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23489646).

Comment: @trincot Sorry, I didn't mean any actual god, I am not religious, it was just an exclamation. If I offended your religious feelings, I am sorry.

Comment: @VladimirF, I understand. Thanks for coming back to it. No offence taken.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are opening the file repeatedly for every value of `J`. This seems wrong.

Secondly, you have not given the variable `NPOIN` a value (greater than 1), so your outer loop on `J` will not stop running (I guess), and this will eventually lead to you trying to read beyond the end of file.

You have nested loops, one on `J` and one on `K`, which seems not logical. You should have one only.

Open the file outside of the `J` loop, and then read line per line until you reach the end of the file:

```
INTEGER :: Reason
INTEGER :: NPOIN

OPEN(unit =90, IOSTAT=Reason, FILE = 'cunnette_xyz.txt', FORM='FORMATTED')
IF (Reason > 0)  THEN
      * ... something wrong ...
      PRINT *, 'Error opening file'
      STOP
END IF
NPOIN = 0
DO
   NPOIN = NPOIN + 1
   READ(*,*, IOSTAT=Reason) A(NPOIN), B(NPOIN), C(NPOIN)
   IF (Reason > 0)  THEN
      PRINT *, 'Error reading input from file. Aborted'
      STOP
   ELSE IF (Reason < 0) THEN
      * ... end of file reached ...
      NPOIN = NPOIN - 1
      PRINT *, 'All data read from file'
      EXIT
   END IF
END DO
* All input should be in A, B, C arrays now, with NPOIN entries

DO K=1, NPOIN
    * Your processing comes here. No more file I/O.
END DO
```

Comment: many thanks for your kind answer. I tried that but I did not work. How should I do the second way line per line?

Comment: First, what do you mean with *it didn't work*. Could you add an new paragraph to your question where you post the code you have used to implement the first idea (only the relevant parts)?

Comment: Why does the code attempt to read the number of lines from the file based on the size of the arrays?  The only `read` statement I see reads only one element from each of three arrays at each time and is executed a `NPOIN` number of times.  `NPOIN` has no value defined in the program, and `k` hasn't at the point of first read, but that doesn't seem to be the point of this answer.

Comment: In the loop on NPOIN you open the file each time again, this is wrong.

Comment: You are right, it does not read the whole array. I corrected my answer. Your code looks stranger the longer I look at it.

Comment: @trincot, thanks A lot. I'm trying to adampt the I/O statement you proposed. hope that it works. I'm really confused!! just to add thar the three columns of input file are x,y,z. I'm trying to tell to the program, if each x,y,z (for one point) is inside my polygon with 14 points, so do ... if not, do...

Comment: But it would zero, no? Fortran allows variables to be created implicitly. That seems a problem for the outer loop, or am I missing something. And why do you have nested loops?